# Add php code to href in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, navigation, href

I've got a problem. Now I have menu like this

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='link1'>link1</a></li>
  <li><a href='link2'>link2</a></li>
  <li><a href='link3'>link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And want, that some links, for example only 2nd link, added a php code in href:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='link1'>link1</a></li>
  <li><a href='<?php ?>'>link2</a></li>
  <li><a href='link3'>link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the menu using the WP menu function then you can't.

If you have built your own menu list then

```
 <?php  $somestring; ?>
```

will suffice. $somestring will be the full URL of the page/post you want to link to. For example:

```
$somestring = home_url('/targetpage');
```

Comment: I have created the menu using WP menu, but maybe with the help of Walker I can do it?

Comment: Possibly. But can I ask what you are hoping to achieve? Using walker is going to involve a whole bunch of code for just one nav link.

Comment: I want to add if logic to the three links in my menu, if will be true show link1, if will be false - show link2